# Scanning a folder recursively and finding the max atime of a file in that folder

Tags: python

Let's say I have a folder "myfolder" that has a structure similar to this

```
myfolder/
myfolder/a/
myfolder/a/1/
myfolder/a/1/i.txt
myfolder/a/1/ii.txt
myfolder/a/1/iii.txt
myfolder/a/2/
myfolder/a/2/i.txt
myfolder/a/2/ii.txt
myfolder/a/2/iii.txt
myfolder/b/
myfolder/b/3/
myfolder/b/3/i.txt
myfolder/b/3/ii.txt
myfolder/b/3/iii.txt
myfolder/b/4/
myfolder/b/4/i.txt
myfolder/b/4/ii.txt
myfolder/b/4/iii.txt
```

and so on..

Now I want to scan myfolder and the atime of every file to print the name of the directory and the latest atime of the directory. Then I want the parent directory of that directory to look at all the subdirectories and print the name of the parent directory with the lastest atime of all the subdirectories and files in the directory as well.  So the list I would generate would show with each directory the latest atime of any file within it's downstream file strucutre.

I tried the follwoing code

```
import os
import sys
import time

# Define the drill_directory function
def drill_directory(directory):
    most_recent = 0.0  # Initialize most_recent as a float
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            atime = float(os.path.getatime(file_path))  # Convert atime to float
            if atime > most_recent:
                most_recent = atime
        else:
            drill_directory(file_path)
    print_most_recent = time.ctime(most_recent)
    print(print_most_recent, directory)

# Define the path to the downloads folder
drill_directory('/Users/Admin/Downloads/')
```

and I got a list of directories with atimes but I noticed some of the subdirectories to a parent directory had more recent atimes than its parent.

Comment: What you want is `os.walk`.  It will recursively return to you all of the directories and files in a directory tree.  There are good examples in the documentation.  HOWEVER, you should know that just listing the contents of a directory (as you are doing) will update the `atime` on some systems.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did try with os.walk, but I need to take an interative approach with a function that nests within itself if I'm going to be able to show just the directories and the atime of the the most recent file within that directory recursively.  That's why I initiate drill_directory in "else".  So it basically says, "scan a folder of all files, wait, I found a directory in here, scan that of all files and report that highest atime".  The last directory to report atime should be the root directory, which should report the most recent atime of any file it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider use `os.stat` to instead of `os.path.getatime`

e.g.

```
file_stats = os.stat(full_path)
ctime = file_stats[stat.ST_CTIME]  # Access creation time from stat object
```

Comment: Why?  What difference do you think that makes?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted.  I realized that, because the function was nested in itself, I had to set a variable to the outout of the nested function and then return the most_recent atime at the end of the non-nested function.  The code below shows all the folders and shows the most recent atime of any file below that folder in the heirarchy.

```
import os
import sys
import time

def drill_directory(directory):
    most_recent = 0.0 
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            atime = float(os.path.getatime(file_path)) 
            if atime > most_recent:
                most_recent = atime
        else:
            atime = drill_directory(file_path)
            print(f"{atime}, {file_path}")
            if atime > most_recent:
                most_recent = atime
    return most_recent

drill_directory('/Users/admin/Downloads/')
```